# Linux at command script keeps repeating

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have changed from nightly cycling services to weekly but after I update the INI, I want the servers to cycle services right then. I figured I could use the 'at' command and send it along with the command that update the INI files.

The problem is this, I am using the same command that I use in the cronjob but instead of just cycling once, as it does with the cron, when I use 'at' the services keep cycling over and over every few minutes.

**Script that uses 'at'**

```
#!/bin/bash

export SRVINI=/u01/home/me/scripts/buildini
SERVERLIST=$SRVINI/serverlist.txt

## Generate the body to send out to each server
touch $SRVINI/body.ini
## copying server.ini commented out as Senthil wants a different copy that he will edit
#cp $SRV_DATA/server.ini $SRVINI/
$SRVINI/generate_body.pl
#rm $SRVINI/server.ini

## scp the body of the ini file to each server
for i in `cat $SERVERLIST` ; do
    scp $SRVINI/body.ini $i:$SRVINI/
done

## Call outside perl script to manipulate the files
for i in `cat $SERVERLIST` ; do 
    ssh $i "source ~/.bash_profile ; cd $SRVINI ; $SRVINI/buildini.pl ; at now + 15 minutes <<< '/u01/home/server/scripts/cycleSRVC.sh > /u01/home/server/logs/cycleSRVC.log 2>&1'"
done

rm $SRVINI/body.ini
```

**Cronjob**

```
15 04 * * 6 /u01/home/me/scripts/cycleSRVC.sh >/u01/me/tomax/logs/cycleSRVC.log 2>&1
```

I have used 'atq' and verified that only one job is created on each server. This makes me feel like my script is being sent correctly via ssh.

I know the cycle script works since it has no problem when its ran as a cronjob.

I have tried different ways of passing the 'at' command and they all create one job on all the servers, they all run but they all start the cycling all over again after a few minutes and I have to manually kill the cycling, kill services and bring them back up.

At a loss on how to proceed. At the moment, when I do updates to the INI I manually cycle services on all 8 servers. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when I do 'atq' after it runs it shows as

```
>atq
22      2014-12-02 22:01 = usr
```

Does this mean it just keeps running and running? Does this mean that the cycle script has an error and so it never finished the at command? If so, why does it work as a cronjob?

**FINAL UPDATE:**

Found the problem. It was in the cycleSRVC.sh script, not with 'at'. 
When my services are starting back up I call:

```
# Restart services
/u01/app/progs/start.sh
sleep 30
```

I have to add a '&' to push start.sh to the background. Not doing that put it in a weird state with sleep being called afterwards. Weird little thing that has caused me a ton of problems.

Posting this here to help anyone else that might have the same frustration.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, to get this question out of the 'unanswered' list. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out nothing was wrong with my implementation of 'at'. The problem was with the cycle script.

Code is in the Final update.